# Lexicographical order in $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: analysis, relations

Consider the set $ \Bbb R^n = \{ x = (x_1, ..., x_n) : x_1, ..., x_n \in \Bbb R \}.$

For $x,y\in \Bbb R^n$, we define $<$,$\leq$ as below:  $$ x<y \iff   j \in \{1,..,n \}  (x_j<y_j)  
\wedge \forall i  \in \Bbb N (i<j \to x_i=y_i).$$

$$x \leq y \iff (x<y) \vee (x=y). $$
$"<"$ defines on $ \Bbb R^n $ the so called "Lexicographical Order".

Prove:
$(a)$ $ \leq $ on $ \Bbb R^n $ defines a order-relation.
$(b)$ $( \Bbb R^n, \leq )$ is total ordered.

*So, could you give me any hints about it, that let me solve alone this exercise? And what is correlation between the lexicographical order and the $\leq$ realtion? Thank you!*

Comment: To make it less abstract, and to help understand what's going on, you might try looking at the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If you can see what's going on in this case, you may be able to understand the higher dimensional cases more clearly.

Comment: I still don't understand at the case of $\Bbb R^2$:(a) $j=2$ then $x_2<y_2$, $i=1<j=2 \to x_1=y_1$. (b) $j=1$ then $x_1<y_1$, $i=0<j=1 \to x_0=y_0$, but $0\notin \Bbb N$.

Comment: You are comparing (ordering) points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by first comparing first coordinates.  If point $A$ has a lesser first coordinate than point $B$, then $A<B$ if $A$ and $B$ have the same first coordinate, then you 'break the tie' by looking at the second coordinate.

Comment: what confused me, was the notation of $\forall i  \in \Bbb N (i<j \to x_i=y_i).$ As $i<j \to x_i=y_i$ means: whatever i $\in \Bbb N$ is,  $\iff i<j$ all couples' components $(x_i,y_i)$ are ever each other the same, or it could be that they are same and/or different???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare on the first component and in case of a tie compare on the second component and in case of a tie compare on the third component...

$\le$ is the non-strict version of $<$.

**Antisymmetry**: if two elements compare both ways ($\le$ and $\ge$), then their first components compare both ways, and there is a tie on the first components; and so on with the next components.

**Transitivity**: if the pairs $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$ are ordered, then their first components are ordered and by transitivity the first components of $(x, z)$ are ordered. In the case of a tie on $(x, z)$, there is a tie on the first components of $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$, and the reasoning applies to the next components.

**Totality**: the first components can be compared and in case of a tie the second components can be compared...

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance about english math terminology but, what is a tie?

Comment: Equal values. Have you heard of a tie break in tennis ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about the correlation, suppose you have a dictionary of all the 4 letter words in the English language. For instance, you have the words $x$ and $y$ where $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (D,A,N,G)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) = (D,A,R,N)$. The reason that DANG comes before DARN in the dictionary is that if we take $j=3$ then $x_3=N$ comes before $y_3=R$ in the alphabet, whereas for $i=1,2$ which are the values of $i<j$ we have $x_1=y_1=D$ and $x_2=y_2=A$.

Now if you represent the 26 letters of the alphabet in order as the integers along the real line, namely $1$ for $A$, and $2$ for $B$, etc., then $(D,A,N,G)$ is represented in $\mathbb{R}^4$ as $x=(4,1,14,7)$ and $(D,A,R,N)$ is represented as $y=(4,1,18,14)$, and we see that $x<y$ in the lexicographic order, just as explained above.

Comment: I think I understood. Thank you!!